# Convert integer to string without knowing buffer size

Tags: c, string, casting, char, int

I want to set a placeholder value (type int) of a path:

**/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value** => **/sys/class/gpio/gpio33/value**

The inserted value is maximum 99 and minimum 1. Because I do not want any empty chars in my path I would like to have the buffer size determined automatically.

This is why I thought of **asprintf()** which does this for strings unfortunately it does not work with integers.

```
#define GPIO_PATH_VALUE "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value"

char * path;

asprintf(path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, 4);
asprintf(path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, 67);
```

Is there a function similar to **asprintf()** which works with integers?

Bodo

Comment: @SIGSEGV you mean? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Your code works for me by making first parameter to `asprintf` as `&path`. Linux/gcc-4.7

Comment: first argument type `char **`

Comment: You can try using strcat to populate the 'path'? Would it be very inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `asPrintf()` takes `char **` as arguement, see this http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf

```
#define GPIO_PATH_VALUE "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value"

char * path;

asprintf(&path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, 4);
asprintf(&path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, 67);
```

As `asPrintf()` do malloc() inside function, in this function `path` wont be pointing to malloced memory address, so you need to send address of `path` so that `asPrintf()` changes the `path` and that will be pointing to malloced address.

Answer (score 2):

As `asprintf()` is a GNU extension, other people facing this problem might want to avoid it.

Instead, it could be done such as

```
#define GPIO_PATH_VALUE "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value"

char * path;

path = malloc(strlen(GPIO_PATH_VALUE) + 5);
// error checking needed!

sprintf(path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, 4); // better snprintf?
// or
sprintf(path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, 67);

path = realloc(path, strlen(path)+1);
// no error checking needed, as we definitely shrink or nop, not extend.
```

if it is clear that `GPIO_PATH_VALUE` stays that simple.

If it gets more complicated, you can do

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char * vbsprintf(const char * format, va_list ap)
{
    va_list ap2;
    va_copy(ap2, ap);
    int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, ap2);
    va_end(ap2);
    char * str = malloc(len + 1);
    if (!str) return NULL;

    vsnprintf(str, len + 1, format, ap);
    return str;
}

char * bsprintf(const char * format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    char * str = vbsprintf(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return str;
}
```

if your system supports `vsnprintf(NULL, 0,` in order to determine the needed length.

Comment: it should be `sprintf(path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, 4);`, its `sprintf(char *, char *,...)`

Comment: @SIGSEGV Of course. I was sure I had changed it. I'm getting old... Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Why `+5`? Why `malloc()` **and** `realloc()`, and not only one `malloc()`?

Comment: To be generic here the necessary length would be `strlen(GPIO_PATH_VALUE) - strlen("%d") + log10(INT_MAX) + 1 + 1);`

Comment: @alk `malloc()` in oder to reserve definitely enough space, and `realloc()` to limit to the actually needed length. Your expression would work as well, but if someone changes the string to a more complicated one, it is not so easy any longer.

Comment: Hmmm ... `+5` "definitely" seems to be to few for a full blown `int`, even taking into accout the `+2` implicitly given by `%d`.

Comment: "The inserted value is maximum 99 and minimum 1".